# Huge delay on a radio stream hybrid Android App using HTML5 audio

Tags: android, html5-audio, audio-streaming, hybrid-mobile-app, internet-radio

I'm developing a online radio streaming app (for a specific radio station) using HTML5/JS and building it for the Android platform with the Intel XDK environment. I've searched for a couple of tutorials over the web and found some sample working example. Here is the relevant code:

`<audio controls="controls"><source src="my stream url" type="audio/mp4"></audio>`

There is an enormous delay before the stream starts playing (even though the first url appeared to have a tiny delay also), around 1 minute or so. I believe both of the streams have the AAC format, and I think there is a little loss in the audio quality too.

I'll be very grateful if anybody can help me, even if by only explaining why I'm experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement to play audio from Android WebView. We noticed it was slow and quality was poor.

We passed this URL to Android application and Played the file using Android Media player.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to appeal to native development... But I'll try to do it as you say! Thanks!

Comment: I have done it using the native development environment and the https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService library! There is still a low volume issue but is nothing compared to what I had earlier. Hope this helps someone else!